# A question about WCF when using app.config

Tags: wcf, app-config

I am a beginner of WCF,I write a simple example of it,and the app.config files of my application as follows:

Host:

```
<services>

  <service name="WCFService.Service.CalculatorService" behaviorConfiguration="calculatorBehavior">

    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://10.1.9.210:8080/GeneralCalculator"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>

    <endpoint address="" binding ="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFService.Contract.ICalculator"></endpoint>

  </service>

</services>

<behaviors>

  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="calculatorBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl=""/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>      
</behaviors>
```

---

Client:

```
<client>

  <endpoint address="http://10.1.9.210:8080/GeneralCalculator/CalculatorService" binding ="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFService.Contract.ICalculator" />

</client>
```

When I run my application,there is an exception:
"The message with To 'http://10.1.9.210:8080/GeneralCalculator/CalculatorService' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.  Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree."

I guess there are some wrong with my configuration file and please give me some hint,

thanks :)

Comment: what's your config for the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<services>

  <service name="WCFService.Service.CalculatorService" behaviorConfiguration="calculatorBehavior">

    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://10.1.9.210:8080/GeneralCalculator"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>

    <endpoint address="CalculatorService" binding ="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFService.Contract.ICalculator"></endpoint>

  </service>

</services>

<behaviors>

  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="calculatorBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl=""/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>

</behaviors>
```

Comment: Please mark as answered and choose the right answer from all the answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your client tries to connect to:

```
http://10.1.9.210:8080/GeneralCalculator/CalculatorService
```

while your server exposes the service at:

```
http://10.1.9.210:8080/GeneralCalculator
```

These two need to match! :-)

So you can either use Rodrigo's answer and add an relative `address="CalculatorService"` to your server's endpoint, or you could change the client's endpoint to point to the same URL as the server exposes right now.

Marc

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the client is trying to hit a Uri that ends in "CalculatorService", whereas the service does not have this suffix on the Uri?  Change the address on the client to match that of the service.